# Get value from input html in codebehind c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I did some research and found out how I can read a value from the input html textbox.

This worked fine for me, but at once it doesn't work.

This is my code, it input html returns null

```
<input type="text" name="inpNickname" placeholder="Nickname" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Nickname" id="txtNickname" runat="server"/>

<input type="text" name="inpPassword" placeholder="Password" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Password" id="txtPassword" runat="server"/>

string Nickname = Request.Form["inpNickname"];
string Password = Request.Form["inpPassword"];
```

If I change the Request.Form[] to the ID's, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try getting it by the ID?

Comment: Yes, that also doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The strings are staying null?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since it is running at the server...

`txtNickname.Value` and `txtPassword.Value` will give you what you  need.

When you specify `runat="server"` you are essentially giving a property to your codebehind class.  So you can access that property and it's properties directly.

Comment: When I tryt this, I can't put .Text after txtNickname and txtPassword

Comment: use txtNickname.Value instead.

Comment: I would recommend using ASP.NET controls (i.e. <asp:TextBox .. />), it'll make your life easier in the long run

Comment: @SamHood I would agree to an extent.  Using server controls is a good choice if you're bound to asp.net web forms.  I would highly recommend using a better platform like mvc though to really make life easier :) ... but that wasn't the original question.

Comment: I agree with both Sam Hood and Bluetoft, if you want to work closer to HTML then use ASP.NET MVC, but I also agree that dressing up HTML controls with `runat="server"` is asking for trouble, especially anyone coming after to maintain your code and you will also be able to fully leverage the `Intellisense` of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a [server control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx)?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNickname" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
var nickName = txtNickname.Text;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string Nickname = txtNickname.Text;
string Password = txtPassword.Text;
```

They're running on the server, see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_controls.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Using `name="inpNickname"` doesn't work, only use the ID so in this case: `txtNickname`

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach:

Frontend :

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="testid"></asp:TextBox>
```

Backend :

```
String test = testid.text;
```

Usually i use these simple server controls, but with complicated forms, and post backs, things are not always so simple...
I've found another surefire way to get the clients control from the back end, even when the control is not found in the code-behind by using thecontrol.text or thecontrol.value for example :

Backend :

```
String test = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$TextboxControlsId"].ToString();
```

This will fetch the contents of the textbox with id: TextboxControlsId, which is defined outside of sitemaster.

If you need to find the ID of your control (most likely it wont conserve the same id you wrote in the front end), you can loop through your form control keys by using :

```
foreach (string s in Request.Form.Keys ) { 
    Response.Write(s.ToString() + ":" + Request.Form[s] + ""); 
}
```