# Not getting value of HTML input type in ASP.NET c# code-behind

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I got the process of getting the value of input field in c# in here:

[Get value from input html in codebehind c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703311/get-value-from-input-html-in-codebehind-c-sharp)

I have a hidden input field in my aspx page like this:

`<input type="hidden" id="lblCountry_val" runat="server" />`

Where the value of the hidden field is put through jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        BindUserInfo();
    })


function BindUserInfo()
{
 document.getElementById('lblCountry_val').value = window.strcountry;
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo"></script>
```

But When I am trying to get the value in Page_Load event in code behind with this:
`Response.Write(lblCountry_val.Value);`

Nothing is being printed. How come?

**EDIT**
I have done this by changing the hidden input field to an invisible textbox and then putting "name" attribute in the tag.

`<input type="text" id="lblCountry_val" name="lblCountry_val" runat="server" style="display:none" />`

And in the code behind:

```
var txt=Request.Form["lblCountry_val"];
```

Though I have not a clear idea how it was done.

Comment: Are you sure the hidden field is being populated in the `BindUserInfo()` function? Try putting an alert after you write to the hidden field and check if the value is stored in it.

Comment: I put : `alert(window.strcountry);` inside the script tags and before the `document.getElementById...` , it's providing value.

Comment: The issue should not be with `window.strcountry`. As your hidden field is a server side control, it's ID will be modified when it renders on the client browser. So doing a `document.getElementById...` on the ID as is won't work. You need to get the client ID in the same way as shown in the first answer below and set the value to `window.strcountry`. After that, do `alert(document.getElementById('<%=lblCountry_val.ClientID%>').value)` to see whether the value has been actually stored in the hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Method -
In aspx, When you set a value to html field using Java script, Field's value doesn't appear in code behind file(aspx.cs). So you have to do additional page post back for set a value to hidden field and then you can able to catch the value in code behind file.

Second Method -
Using  tag, submit hidden field data to relevant aspx page.Then you can catch the value using **Request.Form["lblCountry_val"]** array.

Comment: Would you please provide a piece of code for the second method? I am not getting it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
document.getElementById('<%=lblCountry_val.ClientID%>')
```

This happens because in the most cases the serve side Id of a control is different from its clientId. The way to take it is the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
JavaScript

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var test = "1";
        $("<%=hdn_audio_length.ClientID%>").val(test);
    });
</script>

Html 

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn_audio_length" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="button1_Click" />

C#

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = hdn_audio_length.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example setting hidden fields on submit click.

```
`<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $("#<%= ccnum.ClientID%>").val($("#cc-num").val());
            $("#<%= expdate.ClientID%>").val($("#cc-exp").val());
            $("#<%= cvc.ClientID%>").val($("#cc-cvc").val());
        });
    });
</script>`
```