# Form Field Null in ASP.net Code Behind Despite Runat=Server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is the HTML form field on an ASPX page.

Note the "runat=server" tag that's supposed to let me access it in the code-behind.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="Address1" id="Address1" runat="server" class="form-control input-lg address" placeholder="Full Address" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a snippet of the C# code-behind.

```
string test = Address1.Value;
```

Yet string test fails because Address1.Value is null.

I'm following exactly what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703311/get-value-from-input-html-in-codebehind-c-sharp) but it's always null.  I've searched high-and-low yet everything I've found [suggests the same thing](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-value-of-HTML-Input-TextBox-in-ASPNet-code-behind-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) which doesn't work for some reason. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior during the Page_Load event or during a PostBack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make Sure It Gets To The Server**

Are you doing anything that would trigger an actual `PostBack` that would send the values in your element to the server? .NET will not know that your element has values at all until the actual `<form>` element is posted, which will populate the appropriate values.

If you were to add a button that would submit the form, then your value should be present after the `PostBack` occurs :

[image]

**Close Things Up**

On another note, you'll want to ensure that your `<input>` tag is properly closed with a `/>` as expected to avoid any possible issues with it not being posted as expected :

```
<input type="text" name="Address1" id="Address1" runat="server" class="form-control input-lg address" placeholder="Full Address" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" />
```

**Example**

You can [see a complete example Gist reproducing this here](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/90eb1a0e09f3daeb420642d2d75cbd94).

Comment: I was unaware this required a postback.  That would be why it isn't working.

I need a way to get the data without a postback since it's a single-page app and postbacks reload the whole thing, pushing the user back to the beginning.  

I've been sending data with AJAX; should I just wad up the form fields in the JSON that I was sending in other parts of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding value attribute in your input tag.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="Address1" id="Address1" runat="server" class="form-control input-lg address" placeholder="Full Address" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" value="" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this might be a valuable suggestion, it might be more valuable, in this case, to offer sample code to illustrate what you mean by adding value attribute to input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Strange but for me the control had `ID` in the upper case instead of `id` lower case on the control on aspx side.
e.g.

```
<span runat="server" ID="myLabel">Test</span>
```

When I changed `ID` to `id` that did the trick.

I am still not convinced with this but this resolved my issue.

Hope it can help someone.